# Meaning of Capitalization on The Notation of Gregorian Psalm Tone Endings

Tags: notation, modes, musicology, church-music, chant

As you know, most [Gregorian Psalm Tones](https://media.musicasacra.com/pdf/tones.pdf) have alternative endings. For example, Tone I has 10 possible endings.

[image: Office Psalm Tones]

The endings are denoted by a letter and a number. I understand (correct me if I am wrong) that the letter itself indicates the degree (on the scale) of the last note of the ending. For example, all the "D" endings end in D while all the "g" endings end in G. The number is just a sequential to differentiate between all the possible endings that end on the same note.

Is there any logic, though, behind capitalizing some of these letters? For example:

- why is a capital D used for the "D" endings of Tone I while a lower case g is used for the "G" endings?
- why is a capital A used for the "A" endings of Tone IV while a lower case a is used for the "A" endings of Tone VII?

I apologize if I am misusing a technical term. I am not a musician or a musicologist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Formulas for terminations:** The different intonations of the antiphons have given place to the diverse final cadences in each mode, in order to facilitate the intonation of the antiphon, when psalm ends.
>
> The termination of each particular case is indicated in two ways:
>
> a) placing next to the modal number of the antiphon a letter that indicates the final note of the termination: A, B, C, E, F, G
>
> **8c** [image]
>
> **Uppercase letters are used when the last note of the termination is at the same time the final in the mode; otherwise lower-cases are used.**
>
> When several terminations have the same end, the letters take, in their right superior part, indexes that distinguish them: g, g<sup>2</sup>, g<sup>3</sup>, g<sup>4</sup>.

- [*GREGORIAN CHANT PSALMODY*](http://interletras.com/canticum/Eng/psalmody_ENG.htm), Schola Cantorum Bogotensis
- [*Liber Usualis*](https://ia800604.us.archive.org/14/items/TheLiberUsualis1961/liberusualis.pdf) (p112 - 118)